# How can i create this simple minitest?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml, minitest

I'm new to testing rails applications, i'm trying to do a test of YAML for a friend on Udemy, but i cannot do it, could you help me?

The objective is insert in the text the word "carrot" in "vegetable:" with a space.

The message to modify is this:

```
Fruit: Apple
Drink: Water
Dessert: Cake
Vegetable:
```

I was thinking in something like this, but it's obviously wrong,

```
require "minitest/autorun"
require "./food"

class Evaluate < Minitest::Test
    def test_Vegetable
        assert_equal {"Vegetable"=>"Carrot"},
                     vegetable,
                     "Vegetable: Carrot"
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

So when loading the YAML you have a hash like this, right?

```rb
hash = {
 Fruit: 'Apple',
 Drink: 'Water',
 Dessert: 'Cake',
 Vegetable: 'Carrot'
}
```

Then you could test it like this

```rb
assert_equal hash[:Vegetable], 'Carrot'
```

So we select the key `:Vegetable` from the hash and assert it's `Carrot`.

Comment: I have add an error, please could you help me? Thanks Christian!